# How to install uninstalled app using adb command

Tags: android, installation, adb

Is it possible to reverse the process and to install a system app that has been previously uninstalled with this adb commands?

```
adb shell pm uninstall package_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the APK, you can install it with the following command,

```
adb install example.apk
```

If you dont have the APK, you cannot revert it.

Comment: I did not rephrase myself correctly in the original post. My question refers to system apps. "adb install" does not allow me to install them. Maybe it would work with root privilages, but I don't have them.